kernel compiling error with out-of-the-tree nvidia driver
after many years I decided to recompile my new Acer Nitro 5 laptop's kernel, on Debian 12.
With the vanilla default 6.1.0-28-amd64 kernel I had to install via apt the nvidia drivers.
But, although they are not present in the default kernel from kernel.org, every time I trir to install the compiled linux-6.12.1 it gives me this error on the nvidia driver:
INSTALL /boot
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 6.12.1 /boot/vmlinuz-6.12.1
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.12.1.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.12.1/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Error! The /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/535.183.01/6.12.1/x86_64/dkms.conf for module nvidia-current includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.
This indicates that it should not be built.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.12.1 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:321: install] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:224: __sub-make] Error 2

Should I uninstall them before compiling the new one?
What would be the best practice in this case?
Thanks in advance
Rob

Please provide more details as to what "install via apt the nvidia drivers" means, and what you consequently did with the contents of whatever package that was downloaded/installed.

Hi,
I firstly installed a debian 12 and updated it to kernel 6.1.0-28-amd64, then I installed  via apt the debian packages of the nvidia drivers.
This w-e I decided to download and recompile the linux-6.12.1 kernel with the usual commands but when I launch make modules_install it returns the error I already posted.
I'm just wondering if I should unistall the drivers already installed via apt, recompile the linux-6.12.1 and then install the drivers via source.
Any hint?
thanks in advance

Ask nVidia to open source the code of the driver. Or change the GPU to something more Linux-friendly.
